# Google Workspace addon with BigQuery for usage recording

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm developing an addon of Google Workspace (Google Slides) and having an issue of BigQuery API calling by any of addon user.
An addon will be published to public not for domain only and everyone across the globe may use.
On addon, I'd like to call BigQuery job to run a query and insert a row to record a usage.
However I'm faced an issue of "Access Denied: Project XXX: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project XXX." even I can run this for developer user.
I assume that this is because lacking an access permission to BigQuery API by OAuth.
Should I grant an access to every addon user for BigQuery? Or any standard way to implement this , such as calling BigQuery API by API_KEY, service account etc?
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I used a webapp as an endpoint  (kind of an api) like this `function deleteBlackList() {
  const url=Utilities.formatString('%s?mode=dable',burl());
  const params={"muteHttpExceptions":true,"method":"get","headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  const resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);` That was for getting into Gmail Rest API so I don't know too much about big Q

Comment: Thanks Cooper for your comment! I really appreciate it! Google review team asked me to user service account with OAuth rather than running BQ with user access. I will try that!